# How to get userdefine WebElement name in page object model to print in report log

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I need to get the WebElement name(Userdefine name) for reporting Purpose. Performing Click operation on AddMainConcernLink : If The element is Clicked/not .I need to report "AddMainConcernLink" is Clicked/not found

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "[data-test-id='ECNMainConcernsLink']")] 
private IWebElement AddMainConcernLink;

    public void Click(IWebElement element)
            {
                       element.Click();
                        Console.WriteLine("Perfomed click operation on element : " + element);

             }
```

I want to Print Perfomed click operation on Element: AddMainConcernLink.

Answer (score 0):

I simply pass a descriptive parameter along with the web element to my helper routines.  For example, in a calculator Android app, I have the following:

```
public void clickDegreeRadsToggle() {
    helper.click(degreeRadsToggle, "Degree/Rads Toggle");
}
```

And the helper.click method then logs using the passed description.

Comment: Thanks Bill , Hope this is the Only possible way to Do :-)